# Why isn't my Polymer app working on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

This is my first post here and I have to say, Stack Overflow is such an amazing community for devs. I have visited many times over the years and would like to say a big thank you to everyone for joining together and sharing your knowledge!

So... I love web development and am experimenting with Polymer.

I use the Poylmer CLI and have developed a basic boilerplate for polymer which works perfectly when I run locally on the polyserve / polymer cli.

When I deploy to firebase or open with a native browser (rather than launching polyserve or polymer serve) the app shows as blank. I can't see any console errors either?

Could someone please explain why my web app is not working?

Here is the link to the firebase deployment: https://vapoursnake-91c13.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: The console log shows an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for `webcomponents-lite-min.js`, and if you open that file, it shows an exact duplicate of `index.html`... Seems like your deployment is fouled up somehow. How exactly did you deploy?

Comment: @tony19 I deployed using CLI .. Polymer Build .. then firebase deploy

?What do you want to use as your public directory? build/bundled

 Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes

File build/bundled/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of build/bundled/index.html

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your symptoms. I just deployed the default PSK to Firebase, and the app is running without a problem. I ran `polymer init starter-kit`, `polymer build`, `firebase init`, and `firebase deploy` (with the same answers you've entered).

Comment: btw, I'm using macOS Sierra. What's your OS?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using the cli to run

> Polymer Build

did not include the directories for /src    and   /bower_components

I simply copied them from the root folder.